# How do I call a function in Quickly?

Tags: application-development, quickly

How to call function in quickly?

Here is my code:

```
def finish_initializing(self, builder): # pylint: disable=E1002
    super(projectWindow, self).finish_initializing(builder)
    self.AboutDialog = AboutprojectDialog
    self.PreferencesDialog = PreferencesprojectDialog
def test(self,widget):
    print "clicked"
def on_myButton_clicked(self,widget):
    test()
```

The following error I get:
NameError: global name 'test' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the tutorial video on http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/ ,

If your widget is named "myButton",

```
def test(self,widget):
    print "clicked"
def on_myButton_clicked(self,widget):
    test()
```

This part of your code should be rewritten to below:

```
self.myButton = self.builder.get_object("myButton") 
def test(widget):
    print "clicked"
def on_myButton_clicked(self, widget):
    self.test()
```

In advance, it is necessary to start Glade by `quickly design` command, and to create the button widget.

Answer (score 2):

`test` is a method of the class you are writing so you have to use

```
$self.test(some_widget)
```

where `some_widget` is whatever value you want to use for the `widget` parameter of `test`.

By the way `quickly` isn't a programming language but a tool. The programming language you are using is [Python](http://www.python.org).